# Word for "gait" of handwriting

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word to describe the "consistent" nature of a person's ability to repeatedly write the same word in the same way, eg. as per a signature. Something like "style" but less generic.

It's kind of like the gait describes a persons walk.

So an **example** might be: "John wrote his signature but the ink was feint. He took another pen and, due to his [something], traced the earlier contours subconsciously."

Comment: It is usually simply called "handwriting style".

Comment: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/handwriting) defines the polyseme: << **handwriting**  1.1 A person's particular style of writing. >> This obviously predicates that people generally have a consistent style.

Comment: If you're determined to avoid the word "style" you could perhaps talk about the **flow** of someone's handwriting.

Comment: @mungflesh Have you an example sentence where you would use such a word? I was thinking 'penmanship' might be appropriate, depending on the context of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern.  "Have you ever noticed the stylish pattern in which Jim writes"?

Answer (score 0):

I would utilize "adroit." For example, "The adroit manner by which Jessica writes is impressive." But I also could be completely misunderstanding your question.